# Node-Webkit: Window object become broken after changing location

Tags: javascript, node-webkit

I'm using node-webkit 0.13.4.
When I open second window with `nw.gui.Window.open` and change its location to completely another url (with different domain than previous), I have broken second `window` object and can't do anything with second screen including changing location one more time.
That's how I open window and save instance of new window.

```
_initSecondWindow: function(){
    this.gui = window.require('nw.gui');
    this.gui.Window.open('view/second_window.html', {}, _.bind(function (newWin) {
        this.secondWindow = newWin;            
    }, this));        
}
```

Then I change location of second window

```
function(channel){        
    if (channel == 1){ this.secondWindow.window.location.replace('/view/second_window.html');
        }else{
            var url = 'http://some-remote-address.com/index.php?channel=0';
            this.secondWindow.window.location.href = url;
        }
    }
},
```

Note that we have two different domains (`second_window.html` and `some-remote-address.com`) and load them one by one many times.
At first time when loaded `second_window.html` I change location to some-remote-address.com normally. at second time when I'm changing location from some-remote-address.com to second_window.html all is fine too. But when I change url from second_window.html to some-remote-address.com at second time this.secondWindow.window is broken and have empty location object
When I located on some-remote-address.com and change not url, but change get parameter "channel" all is fine

Comment: What is the full URL of the /view/second_window.html? Did you check to see if you're receiving any DOMExceptions?

Comment: Yes, `/view/second_window.html` It is path of local file and I'm not receiving DOMExceptions.
With node-webkit 0.12 everything was fine.